# psqlodbc.h:54:23: fatal error: iodbcinst.h: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odbc

Erro ao instalar o ODBC do postgresql no ubuntu 64

[image: odbc]

Como devo proceder ?

Comment: Por favor, use texto, não imagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu conseguir instalar o plugin odbc seguindo esses passos:dentro da pasta descompactada do odbc postgresql:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Ou seja, faltava apenas o comando `./configure`? Foi isto que resolveu o problema?

Comment: exatamente. Dentro da pasta descompactada! Eu estava executando na pasta raiz...

Comment: outro detalhe estava usando a vesão 7.X do postgresql quando deveria ter baixado a versão 9.X do odbc..Pura falta de atenção

Comment: Então foi erro de digitação seu, por falta de ler o `README.TXT` e não é necessariamente uma "duvida de verdade". Recomendo que sempre que for instalar algo manualmente procure um readme.txt, readme.md ou readme (sem extensão).

Comment: Outros softwares podem mudar os comandos, podem ter parâmetros adicionais, depende muito da necessidade do software, por isso recomendei que sempre leia o readme que vem dentro do compactado.